# How to make a bullet shoot out the other way?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm creating a game on netbeans and I have the following code for shooting out a bullet.

My problem is that the bullet only shoots out to the right when i want it to shoot out to the left (priority) and the right (depending on what direction the character is facing.) I'm aware that this is using a projectile equation but I am unsure on how to reverse it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `bullet.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(body.getPosition().x - 30, 2.5f)); ` ?

Comment: i've tried minusing that value before, it still shoots out just to the right but in a smaller range

Comment: @zmi You may want to show your implementations for all those methods of yours. `setPosition`, `setLinearVelocity` and so on. If not, we can only guess.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have just updated the question.

Comment: What is `DynamicBody`? Yours or from a library?

Comment: It's from a library.

Comment: Its a body that is able to move. StaticBody is the opposite.

Comment: Need to know what that library is, the answer is in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you want the velocity to be related to the body position. i.e. `body.getPosition().x + 30` seems like a mistake to me. So it should be just:

```
bullet.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(30, 2.5f));
```

And the other way should be:

```
bullet.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(-30, 2.5f));
```

Now `30` may not be enough, as you were relying extra velocity from the body position `x`, so you may need to increase that.

Comment: Was just thinking about the same thing, good catch.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it still is only shooting to the right only. I did increase the 30 to 70 but no changes really.

Comment: you mean decrease to -70 yes?

Comment: when i decreased it to -70, it shot out the bullet to the right but at a tiny angle.

Comment: I think you need to show the code for the `Bullet` class. That isn't behaving as it should it appears.

Comment: i will update the question.